# Howto debug double deletes in C++?

Tags: c++, debugging, memory-management

I'm maintaining a legacy application written in C++. It crashes every now and then and Valgrind tells me its a double delete of some object.

What are the best ways to find the bug that is causing a double delete in an application you don't fully understand and which is too large to be rewritten ?

Please share your best tips and tricks!

Comment: I don't think there's a one-size-fits-all approach.  Ultimately, you need to trace how it came to be that a pointer that had `delete` called on it was still floating about in use after the fact, which boils down to tracing the application logic, unfortunately.  It may help to explicitly set the pointer to `NULL` immediately after the `delete`, because that will catch other access errors via seg-faults.

Comment: @Oli: That only works if the address of the object is stored in only one variable.  While that most likely should be true at the point the object is deleted, in use-after-free scenarios it probably isn't.

Comment: Does valgrind just say there is a double delete, or does it also tell you the size and type of the object and the line at which the second delete occurred?  I think with additional options, you should be able to get the stack trace of the allocation and both deletion attempts.

Comment: What platform?  Some compilers, libraries, and OSes provide tools beyond Valgrind that could be very helpful.

Comment: @Adrian: The appliccation runs on Linux, Windows, *BSD, MacOS X or Solaris. Does any of those have a helpful tool to use ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's some general suggestion's that have helped me in that situation:

1. Turn your logging level up to full debug, if you are using a logger.  Look for suspicious stuff in the output.  If your app doesn't log pointer allocations and deletes of the object/class under suspicion, it's time to insert some `cout << "class Foo constructed, ptr= " << this << endl;` statements in your code (and corresponding `delete`/destructor prints).
2. Run valgrind with --db-attach=yes.  I've found this very handy, if a bit tedious.  Valgrind will show you a stack trace every time it detects a significant memory error or event and then ask you if you want to debug it.  You may find yourself repeatedly pressing 'n' many many times if your app is large, but keep looking for the line of code where the object in question is first (and secondly) deleted.
3. Just scour the code.  Look for construction/deletion of the object in question.  Sadly, sometimes it winds up being in a 3rd party library :-(.
4. **Update**: Just found this out recently:  Apparently gcc 4.8 and later (if you can use GCC on your system) has some new built-in features for detecting memory errors, the "[address sanitizer](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTIzOTU)".  Also available in the [LLVM compiler system](http://llvm.org/Features.html).

Comment: as an addendum to point 3. you might also want to look for assignment operations `Thing* thisThing = otherThing` if you are assigning the pointer of the object to something else (even temporarily), and delete either of them then the object is removed from memory, and any attempt to access, modify, or delete the other will cause problems.

Comment: --db-attach is now deprecated, I don't know which is the solution right now , here's the link saying that they removed it http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/dist.news.html

Answer (score 2):

Yep. What @OliCharlesworth said. There's no surefire way of testing a pointer to see if it points to allocated memory, since it really is just the memory location itself.

The biggest problem your question implies is the lack of reproducability.  Continuing with that in mind, you're stuck with changing simple 'delete' constructs to `delete foo;foo = NULL;`.

Even then the best case scenario is "it seems to occur less" until you've really stamped it down.

I'd also ask by what evidence Valgrind suggests it's a double-delete problem.  Might be a better clue lingering around in there.

It's one of the simpler truly nasty problems.

Comment: Blergh.  Yeah. There's that too.  I've been wrapping things up in concrete stack construction semantics for so long I'd forgotten about the simple problems.

Answer (score 2):

This may or may not work for you.

Long time ago I was working on 1M+ lines program that was 15 years old at the time. Faced with the exact same problem - double delete with huge data set. With such data any out of the box "memory profiler" would be a no go.

Things that were on my side:

1. It was very reproducible - we had macro language and running same script exactly the same way reproduced it every time
2. Sometime during the history of the project someone decided that "#define malloc my_malloc" and "#define free my_free" had some use. These didn't do much more than call built-in malloc() and free() but project already compiled and worked this way.

Now the trick/idea:

```
my_malloc(int size)
{
   static int allocation_num = 0;  // it was single threaded

   void* p = builtin_malloc(size+16);

   *(int*)p = ++allocation_num;
   *((char*)p+sizeof(int)) = 0; // not freed

   return (char*)p+16;  // check for NULL in order here
}

my_free(void* p)
{
    if (*((char*)p+sizeof(int)))
    {
        // this is double free, check allocation_number
        // then rerun app with this in my_alloc
        //    if (alloc_num == XXX) debug_break();
    }

    *((char*)p+sizeof(int)) = 1; // freed

    //built_in_free((char*)p-16);  // do not do this until problem is figured out
}
```

With new/delete it might be trickier, but still with LD_PRELOAD you might be able to replace malloc/free without even recompiling your app.

Answer (score 0):

you are probably upgrading from a version that treated delete differently then the new version.

probably what the previous version did was when `delete` was called it did a static check for `if (X != NULL){ delete X; X = NULL;}` and then in the new version it just does the `delete` action.

you might need to go through and check for pointer assignments, and tracking references of object names from construction to deletion.

Answer (score 0):

I've found this useful: [backtrace() on linux](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/backtrace.3.html).  (You have to compile with -rdynamic.)  This lets you find out where that double free is coming from by putting a try/catch block around all memory operations (new/delete) then in the catch block, print out your stack trace.

This way you can narrow down the suspects much faster than running valgrind.

I wrapped backtrace in a handy little class so that I can just say:

```
try {
  ...
} catch (...) {
  StackTrace trace;
  std::cerr << "Double free!!!\n" << trace << std::endl;
  throw;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, assuming the app is built with MSVC++, you can take advantage of the extensive [heap debugging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/974tc9t1%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) tools built into the debug version of the standard library.

Also on Windows, you can use [Application Verifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd371695%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  If I recall correctly, it has a mode the forces each allocation onto a separate page with protected guard pages in between.  It's very effective at finding buffer overruns, but I suspect it would also be useful for a double-free situation.

Another thing you could do (on any platform) would be to make a copy of the sources that are transformed (perhaps with macros) so that every instance of:

```
delete foo;
```

is replaced with:

```
{ delete foo; foo = nullptr; }
```

(The braces help in many cases, though it's not perfect.)  That will turn many instances of double-free into a null pointer reference, making it much easier to detect.  It doesn't catch everything; you might have a copy of a stale pointer, but it can help squash a lot of the common use-after-delete scenarios.